# Sqoop2 import job from Oracle to HDFS(Text format) inserting string 'null' into HDFS

Tags: import, sqoop, sqoop2

I am trying to import data from Oracle DB to HDFS using Sqoop2. I realized that sqoop2 is inserting a string 'null' value rather than non-string NULL value. Is there an alternative to skip this from happening?
I know there is an alternative in sqoop1 but i m looking for an option in sqoop2.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[Sqoop 1.99.4](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.4/index.html) was released recently with a change that made this more usable. Sqoop2 now uses [NULL](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-1661) in its output.